# Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option english yet

Tags: babel, auxiliary-files

Sorry for the less-than-descriptive title, but I'm new to LaTeX and have no idea how to debug or make sense of errors.

I've modified an invoice template from [here](https://github.com/cmichi/latex-template-collection/) to suit my needs, but I'm getting this puzzling error below.

`Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option english yet`

My `.tex` file is below (with personal information scrubbed):

```
\documentclass[DIN, pagenumber=false, parskip=half,
           fromalign=right, fromphone=true, fromfax=false,
           fromrule=false]{scrlttr2}


\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{longtable}


\newcommand{\stdlohn}[0]{11 \euro}

\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright} 

\setkomavar{fromname}{My Name}
\setkomavar{fromemail}{me@somewhere.com}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+5555 55555}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{}
\setkomavar{frombank}{}



\setkomavar{subject}[]{Invoice for [Services Rendered]/Description}
\setkomavar{yourmail}[Ref. No.]{080213-1}
\setkomavar{yourref}[E-mail]{}
\setkomavar{date}[Datum]{08 February 2012}


%===================================
% footer
\setkomavar{firstfoot}{
    \parbox[t]{\textwidth}{\footnotesize 

    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
         \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{Company:}\\ 
         sdf\\
         sdfdsf\\ \\
         Telefon: \usekomavar{fromphone} \\
         E-Mail: \usekomavar{fromemail} \\
    \end{tabular}
     \hfill{}
     \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
         \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{Legal information:}\\ 
        Sole Proprietor\\
        Tax: 0255 980 24 5\\ \\

        Full Name: sdf\\        
        ID: 32112 5390 081\\
     \end{tabular}
     \hfill{}
     \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}
         \multicolumn{1}{@{}l@{}}{Banking Details:}\\ 
         \usekomavar{frombank} 
     \end{tabular} 
 }}

\begin{document}


%===================================
% receiver
\begin{letter}{
    Mr Client Guy
}

\opening{\ }
\vspace{-1.5cm}

%===================================
\begin{longtable}{p{2.5cm}p{5.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2.5cm}}
    \hline  
    Index & Description & Units(hr) & Total\\
    \hline 

    \textbf{General}\\
    10 & Analysis and planning for data extraction & 4 & 1200,00\\
    20 & Cleaning dirty data & 2 & 600,00\\
    \multicolumn{3}{r}{Subtotal:} & 1800,00\\
    \\

    \textbf{Programming}\\
    30 & Production/implementation of code/solution & 4 & 1200,00\\
    40 & Refactoring for unique cases & 2 & 600,00\\
    \multicolumn{3}{r}{Subtotal:} & 1800,00\\
    \\

    \textbf{Design}\\
    \multicolumn{3}{r}{Subtotal:} & 0,00\\
    \\

    \hline\hline 
\end{longtable}


\begin{longtable}{p{5.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{2cm}p{3cm}}
    \multicolumn{3}{r}{Total Net. Amount}\\
    \hline 
    \multicolumn{3}{r}{} &3600,00\\
    \hline 
    \hline  
\end{longtable}


\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

#### EDIT:

- Deleting my `.aux` file gives me this error:

```
No file angebot.aux.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
\select@language ... \@empty }\languageshorthands 
                                                  {none}\babel@beginsave \cs...
l.58 \begin{document}
```

- Adding `\usepackage{english}` gives a slightly better response but how would I fix it?

```
! Package babel Error: You have used an old interface to call babel
 (babel)                You may expect compatibility problems wit other packages
 .

 See the babel package documentation for explanation.
 Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
  ...                                              

 l.73     \bblstyerror
```

Comment: Try deleting your `.aux` file and re-compile. Does the problem persist?

Comment: Write `\usepackage[english]{babel}` in your preamble.

Comment: Edited Question to include your suggestions.

Comment: Follow @hpesoj626's suggestion. Rather than using `\usepackage{english}`, use `\usepackage[english]{babel}`.

Comment: You loaded `babel`, but then you removed it; it's normal to have an error in these circumstances. Just go past the error hitting the "return" key and in the next LaTeX run all will be normal.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82669/will-cruft-from-a-previous-compile-ever-change-the-final-look-of-my-document

Comment: Besides everything said in previous comments, I had to remove temporary files, which I did via `latexmk -C`, which I assume removes `*.aux` files, as well.

Answer (score 6):

Adding `\usepackage[english]{babel}` solves the error - thank you @hpesoj626

Comment: Please don't convert comments by others into answers of your own.

Comment: Why not, @MartinSchröder? It's hpesoj626 who wrote a comment when he should have given an answer, really. Converting it to an answer for the benefit of others seems exactly the right thing to do in this case!

Comment: @hheimbuerger: Converting them into an answer is fine, but the answer should be community wiki then.