# How can I get US letter output from KOMA-Script's scrlttr2 class?

Tags: koma-script, paper-size, scrlttr2

I use KOMA-Script for most everything, including correspondence. This is painless when I am using A4 paper, but when I try to use US letter, the problems start.

With the `scrartcl` class, `\KOMAoptions{paper=letter}` does the trick.

With the `scrlttr2` class:

If the default class option file is used (`DIN.lco`, I believe), then `\KOMAOptions{paper=letter}` has no effect. The document compiles with this warning:

```
Class scrlttr2 Warning: Letter option file `DIN.lco'
(scrlttr2) needs paper size `a4'.
(scrlttr2) Current paper size is not `a4'!
(scrlttr2) You should add `paper=a4' at the
(scrlttr2) option list of \documentclass!
(scrlttr2) Maybe you know what you are doing,
(scrlttr2) so I do not change this myself.
```

and the output is A4.

If I use `UScommercial9.lco` *without* `paper=letter`, it compiles with this warning:

```
Class scrlttr2 Warning: Letter option file `UScommercial9.lco'
(scrlttr2)              needs paper size `letter'.
(scrlttr2)              Current paper size is not `letter'!
(scrlttr2)              You should add `paper=letter' at the
(scrlttr2)              option list of \documentclass!
(scrlttr2)              Maybe you know what you are doing,
(scrlttr2)              so I do not change this myself.
```

If I use the `UScommercial9.lco`, as in this MWE:

```
\documentclass[UScommercial9]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\listfiles

\KOMAoptions{paper=letter,fromphone=true,fromfax=false}

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Stephen Bosch}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{10 Lemon Lane \\ Sour Orchards BC V0E 0B0}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+1 250 377 4141}

\begin{letter}{Tremulor Nocharme \\ Compliance Officer \\ Special TPS Police
\\ Fram Jammer Building \\ 320, 220 -- 4 Street \\ Treacleton AB T0M 0M0}

\setkomavar{subject}{Late TPS reports 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012}

\opening{Dear Mr. Nocharme,}

Attached please find the TPS reports you requested. Please accept my apologies for the delay.\\

\closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

I no longer receive the warning, but the output is *still* A4.

In addition, when I try to simplify my MWE further by removing the

```
\usepackage[english]{babel}
```

line, I get a series of very strange errors:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\select@language ... \@empty }\languageshorthands 
                                                  {none}\babel@beginsave \cs...
l.8 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\select@language ...me \relax \babel@savevariable 
                                                  \lefthyphenmin \babel@save...
l.8 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
\select@language ...hyphenmin \babel@savevariable 
                                                  \righthyphenmin \expandaft...
l.8 \begin{document}

The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

Class scrlttr2 Info: used language is `english'.
(scrlttr2)           Supported languages are `english', `UKenglish',
(scrlttr2)           `british', `american', `USenglish',
(scrlttr2)           `german', `ngerman', `austrian', `naustrian',
(scrlttr2)           `dutch', `italian', `spanish',
(scrlttr2)           `croatian', `finnish', `norsk' on input line 8.
```

Note: I get this error even though I have deleted all the output files (including aux)! To my knowledge, KOMA-Script and `DIN.lco` do not require babel, and yet the error messages suggest that there are babel leftovers somewhere. If so, I know not where, because I have deleted everything that I can see prior to compiling. I have read [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97814/package-babel-error-you-havent-loaded-the-option-english-yet) and [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82669/will-cruft-from-a-previous-compile-ever-change-the-final-look-of-my-document) already.

The files used (from `\listfiles`) are:

```
 *File List*
scrlttr2.cls    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script document class (letter)
scrkbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-dependent ba
sics and keyval usage)
 scrbase.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (KOMA-Script-independent 
basics and keyval usage)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
scrlfile.sty    2012/06/15 v3.12 KOMA-Script package (loading files)
scrsize12pt.clo    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script font size class option (12pt)
typearea.sty    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script package (type area)
     DIN.lco    2012/07/29 v3.11b KOMA-Script letter-class-option
UScommercial9.lco
 ***********
```

In case it is relevant, I am using XeTeX when compiling.

Comment: As for the second error, if you look at the examples given in the KOMA script documentation, all the `scrlttr2` examples had a `\usepackage[language]{babel}`, apparently it's required although I couldn't find a direct statement saying so. It makes since though why it is needed. I get a more sensible error message: `! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option english yet.`......

Comment: Does option `pagesize` work? This should be enough to write the page size into the pdf.

Comment: @AbdulhaqElhouderi Just remember that KOMA-Script has a German author. And for German `babel` is necceccary ...

Comment: @Josef Either you have misunderstood the option `pagesize` or your comment is misinterpretative … This option is for choosing the output driver, more see in documentation.

Comment: I have been unable to find anything in the koma-script documentation that says that babel is a required package (in one place it is even implied that it as optional: "This is particularly recommended *when* the babel package (see [Bra01]) is used, or language-dependent variables of scrlttr2 are to be changed."). I think the problem has to do with scrlttr2, and not koma-script specifically.

Comment: @Speravir No, the option `pagesize` is not for choosing the output driver. It writes the specified page size into the output file. Otherwise the distribution's page size default is used. If i add `pagesize` to Stephen'S MWE as global option i get a PDF in letter size. Without `pagesize` i get A4. You can add something like `pagesize=pdftex`, but in general koma script is clever enough to detect the output driver itself.

Comment: `DIN.lco` forces page size A4 with `\LetterOptionNeedsPapersize{DIN}{a4}`, which is not a surprise. DIN.lco provides the design of a german business letter defined by DIN. I have not checked the norm, but i guess DIN forces A4. No surprise again for the 'inventor' of the A,B,C paper series.

Comment: @Josef: that DIN.lco forces A4 makes total sense, as DIN 676 and DIN 5008 assume A4. The problem is that UScommercial9.lco specifically asks for a 'paper=letter' which, when provided, is ignored. This behaviour is different from that of scrartcl, to name just one example.

Comment: @Josef I stand corrected. I just noticed that my working example using scrartcl does indeed contain the global option 'pagesize'. There is a section '2.7 Paper Format Selection' in the koma-script docs: "With option pagesize you may select an output driver for writing the paper size into the destination document. Supported output drivers are listed at table 2.6. The default is pagesize=false. Usage of option pagesize without value is same like pagesize=auto... It is recommended always to specify this option. Generally the method without output driver, or with auto or automedia, is useful."

Comment: @Josef Thanks for clarification. I disagree a bit with you, but it may be a lack of my (our?) English knowlegde and of the documentation. And yes, I know writing `pagesize` means `pagesize=auto`.

Comment: @Speravir `pagesize` needs to know the output driver because the code to specify the page size is depending on the output driver. `pdftex` for example offers the primitives `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight`. In case of `dvips` the page size is written in so called special into the dvi, which is read by `dvips`, which then writes the page size into the postscript file. So, pagesize is really not for specifying the output driver in general. It's just a indicator for `pagesize`, which commands should be used. And in general even this is not necessary, as the koma classes can detect themselves.

Comment: @Josef: Yes, see “lack of my … English knowledge”. I meant lack of writing this in proper English. And then there is this description in `scrguien.pdf`: “With option pagesize you may select an output driver for writing the paper size into
the destination document.” This I was referring in my first reply to you.

Comment: Note: Since KOMA-Script 3.17 option `pagesize` is default. With this using `paper=letter` is enough to get a PDF with letter page size. And if you use `geometry` (see answer) it is enough to use option `paper=letter` before loading `geometry` or to load `geometry` with option `letterpaper`. So the problem should be obsolete.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Please try the following MWE (I have changed your MWE a little bit). It should do what you want:

```
\documentclass[UScommercial9,paper=letter]{scrlttr2} % <==== changed
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}                          % <==== changed

\KOMAoptions{fromphone=true,fromfax=false}           % <==== changed

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Stephen Bosch}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{10 Lemon Lane \\ Sour Orchards BC V0E 0B0}
\setkomavar{fromphone}{+1 250 377 4141}

\begin{letter}{Tremulor Nocharme \\ Compliance Officer \\ Special TPS Police
\\ Fram Jammer Building \\ 320, 220 -- 4 Street \\ Treacleton AB T0M 0M0}

\setkomavar{subject}{Late TPS reports 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012}

\opening{Dear Mr. Nocharme,}

Attached please find the TPS reports you requested. Please accept my apologies for the delay.\\

\closing{Sincerely,}

\end{letter}

\end{document}
```

The trick is that your `tex` distribution has a standard paper size of A4. With the command `\usepackage[pass]{geometry}` you advice LaTeX to use the given paper size of the MWE. With pdfLaTeX and XeTeX  it works.

**Update:**
I didn't know KOMA-Script option `pagesize` (thanks @Josef) which also forces LaTeX to write a pdf file with the given paper size, here letter.  So you can change my MWE to (only first changed lines):

```
\documentclass[%
  paper=letter  % paper size
 ,pagesize      % force given paper size in pdf
 ,UScommercial9 % Beta version for testing
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\KOMAoptions{fromphone=true,fromfax=false}
```

**Update 2:**
Since KOMA-Script 3.17 option `pagesize` is default. So you don't need to set it explicitly or to load `geometry` (Comment of @Schweinebacke).

Comment: It works fine with XeTeX as well.

Comment: This worked with XeTeX, but I don't understand why geometry should be necessary at all. First, 'paper=<paper_size>' is a KOMA option that is designed for exactly this purpose, and in fact if I use UScommercial9.lco without providing paper=letter as a KOMAOption, I get an error message saying scrlttr2 is expecting 'paper=letter'! Second, 'paper=<paper_size>' works exactly as expected with scrartcl.

Comment: @StephenBosch You just have to add the global option `pagesize`, see my comment. Then the specified page size is written to the output file, instead of the distribution's default.

Comment: @StephenBosch I didn't know option `pagesize`. I tested it and it works. I added the changed parts of my MWE to my answer ...