# Conflict using babel and standalone's convert-Option

Tags: babel, incompatibility, standalone

I recently started using `standalone` to compile a tikzpicture and convert it to PNG. Thus I use the following type of Document together with

```
\documentclass[convert,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
  \tikz\node {Hallo da drau"sen};
\end{document}
```

and get the error message

```
(C:\Users\...path..\Test.aux

! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option ngerman yet.

See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.3 \select@language{ngerman}

You may proceed, but expect unexpected results

)
```

Neverless the result indicates that the `ngerman` additions by `babel` were loaded (i.e. the ß for `"s` is being typeset correctly).

---

I am aware of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97814/package-babel-error-you-havent-loaded-the-option-english-yet) which proposes deleting **all** auxiliary files. But on the next run the error is back.

---

Further investigation shows the possibility to condense the problem even more:

```
\documentclass[convert]{standalone}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
  X
\end{document}
```

The error however does **not** occur without the `convert` option or without `babel`. The choice of language doesn't seem to make any difference.

Comment: Interesting bug of `standalone`.

Comment: @egreg Should I probably inform the maintainer of this bug?

Comment: Yes, you should.

Comment: @DavidWoitkowski Done: https://bitbucket.org/martin_scharrer/standalone/issues/16/convert-option-and-babel-package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One wonders why the class loads in this case the `aux`-file so early. But probably there is a reason ...

Imho you can simply ignore the error. It doesn't do harm. You can avoid it by creating a `standalone.cfg` in the current folder with the content

```
 \RequirePackage[ngerman]{babel}
```

Then babel is loaded earlier.