# Change Language in \usepackage[<language>]{babel}?

Tags: errors, languages, babel

I've been trying to change the language of my LaTeX document by replacing `\usepackage[swedish]{babel}` with `\usepackage[english]{babel}` but I only get this message:

```
! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option swedish yet.
```

I've read in an other question at this forum that compiling enough would solve the problem, but that doesn't work for me. Does anyone know what I should do?

Comment: When you change languages you also need to delete your `.aux` file.  Try that and recompile and the error should disappear.

Comment: In addition to Alans comment, that comment you have read that it is enough to recompile, depends on how which options the editor passes to `latex`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will cruft from a previous compile ever change the final look of my document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/82669/will-cruft-from-a-previous-compile-ever-change-the-final-look-of-my-document)

Comment: It is sufficient if you just compile once again. The inappropriate `.aux` has been overwritten with the first compiler run and will now be read correctly.

Comment: Yes, I read that question before I posted and it says that bad things happens in the .aux file, but not really that you should remove it and everything would work. A newcomer to LaTeX like me would not dare to remove a file just because it was causing the trouble.

Comment: @ThorstenDonig Whether or not you need to delete the `.aux` depends a lot on your editing environment.  With TeXShop for example, recompiling is not sufficient to remove the error.

Comment: @Djamillah you could always rename it to myfile_junk.aux if you were worried.  Also you can look at the creation time and date - it was clearly created at compile time.  Personally my default compile macro kills the .aux (etc.) after compiling - I have to hit a different key if I want to keep my .aux (or more likely .log and .bbl)

Comment: I'm not seeing this as a dupe: this is very focussed on a specific issue, and is a pretty common problem. In particular, it's not caused by an _error_ in the auxiliary files.

Comment: Please, close voters, this is not really a duplicate, even though the answer is contained in the linked question. The supposed duplicate is much more general. I've linked to it in my answer, but I think we should leave this question open.

Comment: I had the same issue and I solved as below
choose recompile from scrach, in the Recompile options.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

This is a very common error with `babel`, and is solved by removing the `.aux` file whenever you change languages.

When you use `babel` it writes information to the `.aux` file that refer specifically to the language you have chosen. In your case, for example, when you select `swedish` as the babel language it does two things: (i) it loads a set of macros related to Swedish and (ii) it (minimally) writes the following to the `.aux` file.

```
\select@language{swedish}
\@writefile{toc}{\select@language{swedish}}
\@writefile{lof}{\select@language{swedish}}
\@writefile{lot}{\select@language{swedish}}
```

The command `\select@language{swedish}` tells TeX to use the specific macros defined for Swedish.

The `.aux` file is used for storing information that will be reused on the next compilation.  See

- [What are the situations where you have to compile a document more than once?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/35832/2693)

for some more information on this.

`babel` writes to the `.aux` file because it changes the names of things like the table of contents and list of figures according to the chosen language.

Now, when you change the language without deleting the `.aux` file, and compile your file, TeX reads in the `.aux` file and encounters the `\select@language` command. But since you have changed the language, the macros for Swedish haven't been loaded, and you get the error you received.

The `babel` package is not the only package that can sometimes require you to delete the `.aux` file.  See the following more general question for information about them:

- [Will cruft from a previous compile ever change the final look of my document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82669/2693)

### Newer versions of `babel`

If you are using an up-to-date system with `babel` version 3.22 or greater, you should no longer receive this error, but instead should see a warning like the following:

```
Package babel Warning: Unknown language `swedish'. Very likely you
(babel)                requested it in a previous run. Expect some
(babel)                wrong results in this run, which should vanish
(babel)                in the next one. Reported on input line xxx.
```

Comment: Starting from `babel` 3.22 unknown languages are not errors any more, they have been downgraded to warnings: https://lists.dante.de/pipermail/ctan-ann/2018-June/011573.html

Comment: @moewe Finally. :) I noticed that looking through the code. But there are still enough older systems around for this question to be relevant. I've updated the answer though.