# Babel Error: Undefined Control Sequence

Tags: errors, languages, babel

I'm running into a bizarre issue with the Babel package that I haven't seen before and would love some help figuring out a solution.

First, I'll give an example of something that does compile correctly (using pdftex) on my computer:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hebrew, english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
Document Text.
\end{document}
```

However, when I remove the word `hebrew`, it no longer compiles and gives me the following error (taken from the log file):

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\bbl@set@language ...ge {\languagename }}\bbl@for 
                                                  \bbl@tempa \BabelContentsF...
l.6 \begin{document}

? 
! Emergency stop.
\bbl@set@language ...ge {\languagename }}\bbl@for 
                                                  \bbl@tempa \BabelContentsF...
l.6 \begin{document}

End of file on the terminal!
```

I have noticed that the same error occurs when using Arabic and English.

I just recently updated to TeX Live 2013; I also just updated all my packages. After running into this issue, I reinstalled all babel packages with the TeX Live Utility and tried to compile the document again with no luck.

I also just recently installed GNU Aspell with a bunch of dictionaries, including Arabic, Hebrew, and English. I can't imagine that would cause this issue, but I thought I'd mention it. Also, I am on a Mac.

Here is output from `\listfiles` for the english document:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\bbl@set@language ...ge {\languagename }}\bbl@for 
                                                  \bbl@tempa \BabelContentsF...
l.6 \begin{document}

? r
OK, entering \nonstopmode...
[1

{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./FIT2.aux)

 *File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
inputenc.sty    2008/03/30 v1.1d Input encoding file
    utf8.def    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   t1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  ot1enc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
  omsenc.dfu    2008/04/05 v1.1m UTF-8 support for inputenc
   babel.sty    2005/11/23 v3.8h The Babel package
 english.ldf    2005/03/30 v3.3o English support from the babel system
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX file
 ***********

 )
```

Comment: Have you tried deleting the `.aux` file? [Changing babel languages generally requires it.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127314/627)

Comment: Yes I have - I still get the same error message.

Comment: Sounds like a job for `\listfiles`. Could you add that to the input and edit in the `*File list*` you get from the log? I guess you might need to do two runs, one with just `english` and one with just `hebrew` as the `babel` options.

Comment: Try to press `r` when the terminal pauses and hit `enter` and do this twice.

Comment: try copying the file to a different name, omitting hebrew, and try running that.  does the error still occur?  if not, it's probably something in another automatically generated file, like `.toc` or `.lof`.  check for those too, and get rid of them before rerunning.

Comment: Okay some responses to others' suggestions:

Joseph - I did that and have edited my original comment with that information (or at least will soon after adding this comment).

Sigur - did this, when I run pdflatex it does output the pdf but the words "englishtoc,lof,lot" appear right before "Document Text."

Barbara - I changed the name and omitted hebrew before running Sigur's suggestion; see above for what happened. There are no `.toc` or `.lof` files, but the output mentioned above seems to indicate that they may be an issue.

Comment: You have a very outdated Babel subsystem somewhere; with TeX Live 2013 it should be `babel.sty 2013/05/16 v3.9f`. Look for `babel.sty` in the log file and report the path where the file is loaded from.

Comment: I looked - it is loading if from my texmf folder - `~/Users/myusername/Library/texmf/tex/latex/babel/babel.sty` - whereas my other style files such as inputenc.sty are loading from the new texlive distribution - `/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty`. When I open the TeX Live Utility, it isn't indicating that the Babel package is out of date. How can I get TeX Live to recognize that this is out of date and replace my babel style files? Sorry for what is probably a basic question...

Comment: I just deleted the `babel` folder it was calling in `Library` and it now works - thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that I had an outdated version of `babel` in my `Library` folder (`/Users/username/Library/texmf/tex/latex/babel/`). After deleting this outdated version, LaTeX used the correct, updated version found in the 2013 distribution (`/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/tex/latex/generic/babel/`). Documents now compile correctly!