# Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the language french yet

Tags: errors, packages, babel, labels, french

I just got LaTeX up and running and started following some basic instructions.

The first time I followed the beginning over here: http://ftp.ctex.org/pub/tex/tools/editors/TeXworks/manual.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper}
\usepackage[francais]{babel}
\title{Premier document}
\author{Un TeXnicien}
\date{}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
Voici un texte accentué en français!
\end{document}
```

Now, afterwards I restarted the program and made a new TeX file. However, this time I can't run this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Because I get the error in the title. What's up with this? I'm using TeXworks.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127314/change-language-in-usepackagelanguagebabel?lq=1 for an likely explanation and solution: delete the `.aux` file

Comment: perhaps your new file has the same name as the previous one? anyway have you tried compiling a second time? or isn't there a way to tell  `TeXworks` to remove all auxiliary files?

Comment: Deleting the `*.aux` file is not stringently required. An anew compiler run should do the trick already.