# Strange hyphenation behaviour with babel's italian option

Tags: spacing, babel, hyphenation

As an odd recurrence with many previous documents (and by 
subsequent trials and errors), I noticed that with this default, reduced MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
%
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenx}
%
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
%
%\usepackage{fixltx2e}
%
%\numberwithin{equation}{section}
%\numberwithin{figure}{section}
%\numberwithin{table}{section}
%
\usepackage[english,italian]{babel}
%
\begin{document}
%
All'interno di una semicirconferenza vi è uniformemente distribuita una carica $Q$, definibile 
%
\end{document}
```

some lines of text contain evidently too much space between words; as the output clearly shows:

> [image]

To me it's difficult to think that `babel` wasn't able to recognize the correct hyphenation for the last line word `carica`, as the legal breaking `ca-ri-ca` should have sufficed to decrease the word spacing of the first line.

The rather surprising part came out after deleting the `italian` option, because at first this error was shown:

```
! Package babel Error: You haven't loaded the option italian yet.
See the babel package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
...                                            
l.3 \select@language{italian}                      
?
```

I honestly do not know *why* this error message is supposed to exist. However, by disregarding this, the generated output is:

> [image]

Now the last word of the line was wrongly hyphenated (as suspected); but still, this leads to this final question: *why `babel` couldn't simply hypenate `carica` as `ca-`, gaining the correct word spacing, instead as leaving those ugly voids?*. I know that this word is not esoteric, and should be enlisted into the hypen dictionary.

And, for the sake of completeness, *why there is such an error when I delete a language option?* My thought about this could be that whenever an option is modified, the `*.aux` file somehow interferes with the new declaration, hence pointing out an error; but I'm not sure.

Comment: On the source of the error see: [Change Language in \usepackage\[\]{babel}?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/127314).

Comment: @AlanMunn Thank you, I'm happy to see that my intuition wasn't too far away from the truth.

Comment: And on the hyphenation problem itself, I think this is an artefact of your example.  If you add some more text to the paragraph you will get the expected hyphenation.

Comment: @AlanMunn Good Golly, you're right! But, if a new line has been created, why doesn't the last word (in this case, `carica`) hypenate correctly in the first place?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hyphenation is taken into consideration, but not used, because it would give higher demerits. Here's what I get

```
@firstpass
@secondpass
[]\T1/cmr/m/n/10 All'interno di una se-mi-cir-con-fe-ren-za vi <E8> uni-for-me-men
-te di-stri-bui-ta una 
@ via @@0 b=189 p=0 d=49601
@@1: line 1.0 t=49601 -> @@0
ca-
@\discretionary via @@0 b=0 p=50 d=2600
@@2: line 1.2- t=2600 -> @@0
ri-
@\discretionary via @@0 b=25 p=50 d=3725
@@3: line 1.3- t=3725 -> @@0
ca $\OML/cmm/m/it/10 Q$\T1/cmr/m/n/10 , de-fi-ni-bi-le 
@\par via @@1 b=0 p=-10000 d=10100
@\par via @@2 b=0 p=-10000 d=50000100
@\par via @@3 b=0 p=-10000 d=50000100
@@4: line 2.2- t=59701 -> @@1
```

(I just loaded `T1`, but the result is almost the same with OT1).

What's the problem? As you clearly see, the added `\finalhyphendemerits`, that `babel-italian` sets to a very high value (50000000), make undesirable a hyphen in the last but one line. With the default value of 5000, the hyphen would be added.

---

What does that listing mean? It represents TeX's computations for line breaking.

- `\@firstpass` means what TeX does without trying hyphenation; nothing shows because there's no way to respect the constraints given by the value of `\pretolerance`.
- `\@secondpass` shows the real computations; the first feasible point is after `una`; before it, no good place for line breaking can be found; note that `@@0` represents the start of the paragraph.
- `@` at the start of a line denotes a candidate for a break point; then the badness, the available penalties and the demerits are shown.
- `@@1` represents this found line break point; the line is classified `1.0`, that is, line 1 which is “loose”;
- `@@2` is another good candidate for a line break, with total demerits 2600; `line 1.2-` means it's a “decent” line, but with a final hyphen.
- `@@3` would produce higher demerits, with a “tight line”, which ends with a hyphen.

After “definibile” there's `\par`, so TeX tries to find the “shortest path” adding also the “global demerits”, in particular `\finalhyphendemerits` if the last but one line is hyphenated. So the route is from `@@4` (the final break forced by `\par`) via `@@1` to `@@0`.

Comment: Interesting! Although it's rather obscure why `\finalhyphendemerits` has been set to this value and not the defalut. As it can be seen on the MWE there isn't any package affecting this value.

Comment: @AndreaL. Ask Claudio Beccari, who wrote the module of `babel` for Italian. I have always thought it's too high a value. A short paragraph will suffer from it, a longer paragraph will have sufficient flexibility that a value like the default (5000) is enough.

Comment: I will surely follow your advice (as soon I'll have the time), because the style of many documents I'm used to write consists of very small paragraphs (explanations of mathemathical steps); this issue evidently comes to the eye as a punch. On the last bit, do you know where I could get more specific information of `\finalhyphendemerits` et similia?

Comment: @AndreaL. The TeXbook or TeX by Topic (`texdoc texbytopic` if you have TeX Live).