# Changing Language

Tags: languages

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/45858/263287

I am working on my own Norwegian and Latin interlinear.
I copied Alan Munn's template and edited the main and secondary language to

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}
\setmainlanguage[variant=bokmal]{norwegian}
\setotherlanguage{latin}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage{datatool}
\usepackage{expex}
```

however, I get an error:
! Package polyglossia Error: language portuguese is not loaded. Please load it
before using it..

See the polyglossia package documentation for explanation.
Type  H   for immediate help.
...

l.2 ...tlanguage *[variant=brazilian,]{portuguese}

Please help.

Comment: compile again or delete the aux-file.

Comment: thank you for the prompt reply.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Language in \usepackage\[<language>\]{babel}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127314/change-language-in-usepackagelanguagebabel)

Comment: Or a `polyglossia` specific version: [Polyglossia breaks when changing default language from English](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/584922)

Comment: hi Alan. I ran your code again and this time, it gave me this error

! Package datatool Error: Can't assign \GreekText : there is no key `Greek' in 
data base `text'.

See the datatool package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.82 }}}

Comment: @monstermash I can replicate this error if I use `\DTLsettabseparator` instead of explicitly using `\DTLsetseparator{...}` with an actual tab in the source as the argument. Perhaps you've changed that line in some way?

Comment: no sir. I did not change the line in any way.

Comment: Then I don't know. The code still runs without errors for me otherwise. Is it possible that the tab got changed to spaces by your editor when you pasted the code?

Comment: no. I simply copy and pasted. Your method with datatool is convenient and I have no experience in LaTeX.

Comment: @monstermash What you did is not the issue; the question is whether your editor changed the pasted code by itself. If you put your cursor immediately to the right of the opening `{` in `\DTLsetseparator{...}` and then hit the right arrow, does it jump immediately to the immediate left of the closing `}`? It should if it has been pasted correctly.   Also you need to make sure the `.csv` file has not been messed up by e.g. Excel if you've opened it and saved it using that. The problem you're getting is a problem with reading the `.csv` file.

Comment: oh yes. thank you Alan, I did in fact mess up with the CSV file. 
One more thing, how do I change the Capitulo 2 into something of my choice?

Comment: That's too vague a question. The chapter title formatting is set by `titlesec` which gives you lots of possibilities. The text itself should adapt automatically to your main language. It's contained in the `\chaptertitlename` macro. There are plenty of questions about formatting chapters and sections on the site. But this example isn't the best place to start if you're really unfamiliar with LaTeX. See [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](//tex.stackexchange.com/q/11) for some good resources to learn from.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will just stick to the default for now.

Comment: hi Alan, where do I change the chapter counter? It is stuck at 2.  Do I change it here?
\setcounter{chapter}{1}