# Package hyperref doesn't work anymore - break down

Tags: xetex, hyperref, todonotes

I'm working on a documentation for several weeks. To link the table of content with the text of the document I was working with the package hyperref. Until today everything went fine. Today I installed the package todonotes. After installing it was not possible anymore to create the PDF file. Tests show that the problem is the hyperref package. I tried a lot of steps to make it working again:

1. Deinstallation of package todonotes
2. Deinstallation of package hyperref and new installation of it
3. Deinstallation of MikTex and TeXstudio and new installtion of both (I thought that maybe todonotes had overwritten some important things for hyperref)

Nothing of this is working. If I try to compile my documentation without using hyperref it is working. But as soon as I include the hyperrefpacking the compilation breaks down and ends in an endless loop - the PC is working and working and working but nothing happens. After a while the CPU workload gets down but still nothing is working. I don't get any error or something else. Does anybody know the reason for that problem? I don't understand why it was working since I have tried to install the todonotes package. If I try to compile the documentation on another PC the same problem occur.
Some additional information: I'm using MikTex 2.9, TeXstudio 2.9.4 and the XeLatex compiler, because I'm using some packages which require XeLatex. But also if I use the LaTex compiler the problem occurs. Please, can anybody help?

Comment: if you add (or remove) hyperref it is often necessary to remove all aux and toc files so they may be rebuilt in an appropriate way. Doesn't normally loop though.

Comment: Thanks a lot David. I deleted all files instead of .tex and now it is working again :) I would never have found the solution without your help

Comment: relevant: [Will cruft from a previous compile ever change the final look of my document](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82671/579)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add (or remove) `hyperref` it is often necessary to remove all `aux` and `toc` files so they may be rebuilt in an appropriate way.