# Bibliography in latex apa problem

Tags: bibliographies, errors, compiling, apa-style

i am a passive follower of this forum for quite a time and it usually helped my but now i can't figure a probleme. I want to have a simple bibliography (prefered) in APA but it does not work. I tried almost everything but it displays a error.

```
\documentclass[12pt,titlepage]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\synctex=1

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[a4paper,lmargin={3cm},rmargin={2cm},tmargin={2cm},bmargin={2cm}]{geometry}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{nicefrac}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false,pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
test test

test \cite{dohmen2011}


\bibliography{Literatur}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\end{document}
```

This are the error messages:

> ```
> Undefined control sequence. test \citet
> Undefined control sequence. dohmen2011}
> Undefined control sequence. \APACinsertmetastar
> Environment APACrefauthors undefined. \begin{APACrefauthors}
> Undefined control sequence. \BCBL
> Undefined control sequence. \BCBL {}\ \BBA
> Undefined control sequence. \BCBL {}\ \BBA {} Wagner, G\BPBI
> \begin{thebibliography} on input line 1 ended by \end{APACrefauthors}. \end{APACrefauthors}
> Undefined control sequence. \APACrefYearMonthDay
> Undefined control sequence. {\BBOQ
> Undefined control sequence. {\BBOQ}\APACrefatitle
> Undefined control sequence. ...nants, and behavioral consequences}.{\BBCQ
> Undefined control sequence. \APACjournalVolNumPages
> Undefined control sequence. \PrintBackRefs
> Undefined control sequence. \PrintBackRefs{\CurrentBib
> ```

This is the bib-file:

```
@article{dohmen2011,
  title={Individual risk attitudes: Measurement, determinants, and behavioral consequences},
  author={Dohmen, Thomas and Falk, Armin and Huffman, David and Sunde, Uwe and Schupp, J{\"u}rgen and Wagner, Gert G},
  journal={Journal of the European Economic Association},
  volume={9},
  number={3},
  pages={522--550},
  year={2011},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
```

Comment: Which error? Are you running `bibtex`?

Comment: Undefindes control sequence and stuff like apacrefauthers undefined

Comment: At least i try... It usually always worked but now there are these errors

Comment: Please copy the exact error messages into your question.

Comment: i copied you all error messages and the entry of the bib file

Comment: You should load the package `apacite` via `\usepackage{apacite}` too.

Comment: I already tried this but there are still error messages. With and without natbib package

Comment: Delete all your aux files and use `\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}`

Comment: No ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you are trying to use the `apacite` bibliography style without loading the `apacite` package.  Since you are using `natbib` citation commands you should load the package with the `natbibapa` option:

```
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite}
```

See the following question for more discussion:

- [What is the relationship between natbib, apacite package, and apa document class?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/263793/2693)

The reason your document still failed when you first added the `\usepackage` command was because the auxiliary files related to the previous `latex` + `bibtex` compilation were still around. Whenever you change packages associate to the bibliography (and some other packages) it's always a good idea to delete all the auxiliary files before recompiling.

See the following question for some more discussion:

- [Will cruft from a previous compile ever change the final look of my document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82669/2693)