# Underscore in label name when switching to using hyperref

Tags: hyperref, auxiliary-files

Compiling the following document first without hyperref, then with hyperref (consecutively), produces the error

```
Runaway argument?
{\@firstoffive }\fi  
./test.tex:7: Paragraph ended before \Hy@setref@link was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par 
l.7
```

Why is that so? (It is related to the underscore in label in section, I suppose, but I am not sure.)

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\section{Mathematical Proofs\label{sec_proofs}}
\ref{sec_proofs}

\end{document}
```

Comment: no the problem is that without hyperref labels store two values (number and page), with hyperref five (number, page, name, destination, and a free one). One could perhaps catch it, but the real plan is to use five values without hyperref too.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Curiosity: Is the official status of the fifth field "free"? Isn't it used for the url for `xr`?

Comment: @gusbrs I don't think that it is used anywhere, at least I never saw a use somewhere.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm pretty sure it is used by `xr`, but I don't recall why I think this. If I'm not mistaken, it belongs to the imported labels of the external file, so you never see the field in the .aux file, you have to show the labels directly. I could make sure of this, if you'd like.

Comment: Removing the `aux` file fixes the error, which is triggered also when there is no underscore.

Comment: Progressing in TeX is difficult. Programming in TeX, use aux, patch internal commands, and ensure that nothing breaks even when the aux of with-package is compiled without-package or vice-versa is even more difficult. (for one, you need appropriate no-op `\providecommand` to make sure that the document doesn't break when your package is removed.)

Comment: Urlike is a member of the LaTeX project so "in theory" it would be possible to change the kernel to use 5 values as well (except... would that break a lot of packages? I'm not sure. Also worst-case you get error when you keep the aux and upgrade LaTeX version, but this one is rather unlikely)

Comment: Reverse question of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82671/250119 I guess.